# What is the basis behind default installed applications?

Tags: default-programs

well there are many packages and applications installed by default in Ubuntu, which some relate to old choices made by Canonical like using Unity and stuff like that. But I'm wondering about the decision when they select an specific software over other similar ones to be installed by default on the OS, for example `transmission`.

- So is there any explanation by Canonical over these kinds of decisions and selections?
- Are these decisions more about system stability and performance rather than popularity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark Shuttleworth had a [blog post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/568) about this and the key questions are ...

> In evaluating an app for the Ubuntu default install, we should ask:
>
> - is it free software?
> - is it best-in-class?
> - does it integrate with the system settings and preferences?
> - does it integrate with other applications?
> - is it accessible to people who cannot use a mouse, or keyboard?
> - does it look and feel consistent with the rest of the system?

The discussion about default apps starts at the Ubuntu Developer Summit. [16.05](https://launchpad.net/sprints/uos-1605) was the last online one (UOS). But changing an app to another will need a blueprint or something similar before it gets picked up (there has been an ongoing discussion on replacing firefox for chromium for [years](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/chromium-to-replace-firefox-as-default-browser-in-ubuntu). That one is more likely to be based on sentiment and popularity than any of the above).